# what degree of fredom one should use while calculating standard diviation for standardizing data

Tags: statistics, data-cleaning

I am writing a function to standardize the data and I found out that we can choose either ddof = 0 or ddof = 1, so I got confused that which one to choose and why? Does this make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ddof represents the degrees of freedom adjustment when you subtract from N in the standard deviation formula below. So I suggest that if you are working with a sample from a population, and you want an unbiased estimate then you use ddof=1. If you want to consider it as a population you can use ddof=0.

$$
S=
\sqrt{
\dfrac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N
\bigg(
X_i-\bar X
\bigg)^2
}
$$

Comment: In addition to @Ralph's answer, usually the choice of DDOF does not make much impact since 1) the difference is small for large N; and 2) it is just a scaling to feature which (AFAIK) every models can cope with.

Comment: Amazingly, the square root of that unbiased estimator of variance is a biased estimator of standard deviation.

Comment: I had never heard of the term Delta Degrees of freedom, but had to look it up.  Not a statistical term